# Angular Call webapi before changing routes

Tags: angular, angular-router

--- Want to call webapi before routes change in Angular ---

I have two pages with two components:

**PAGES:**
HOME & ABOUT

**COMPONENTS:**
home.component.ts & about.component.ts

When I redirect from **HOME to ABOUT** page and vice versa, I want to call a Webapi before it routes to another page

I tried 2 things mentioned below :

1. ngOnDestroy
2. Subscribe Router Events

**EXAMPLE:This is what I have tried so far**

Let's say I am navigating from Home => About page, so inside the home component method, Below are the two cases

Home.component.ts :::: Calling Webapi method inside ngOnDestroy method.

------------------------------------------ ngOnDestroy ---------------------------------------------------------

public ngOnDestroy(): void {

```
    this.updateChanges(); // Indside this method, I have a service class that handles all http requests call

    // Unsubscribe from all subscriptions
    this._unsubscribeAll.next();
    this._unsubscribeAll.complete();
```

}

----------------------------------------------- Router ------------------------------------------------------------

Home.component.ts :::: Calling Webapi by Subscribing Router change events

public ngOnInit(): void {

```
this._router.events.subscribe((ev: Event) => {
           if (ev instanceof NavigationStart) {
                this.updateChanges(); // Indside this method, I have a service class that handles all http requests call
           }
        }
);
```

}

---

PROBLEM : Inside network tab in browser, I can see that Webapi is getting called but status is showing Cancelled. Any idea why?

FYI: Webapi is correct only. It is working fine withing the page.

Comment: The method updateChanges probably uses the httpClient and subscribes there. So using onDestroy and unsubscribing from all the subscriptions would cancel the just made request. The router approach resulted also in a cancelled request?

Comment: Add the code for `Router change events` to app.component

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate for your quick response.

Yes you are right. this._unsubscribeAll.next(); and this._unsubscribeAll.complete(); were causing the problem. Only for testing purpose I commented it out for a while and it got worked.

I can move it to app.component but the problem is not even single information of home.component available at app.component level...

and these two lines this._unsubscribeAll.next(); and this._unsubscribeAll.complete(); are required, so the question is how I will achieve it? Do I need to redesign some architecture?